# Replace multiple whitespace in string with multiple special char in Java

Tags: java

```
String str = "hello  there, what are   you doing";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", "?"));
```

output: hello?there what are?you doing

expected output: hello??there what are???you doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one line regex which uses replaces whitespace using look ahead `(?=\s)` and look behind `(?<=\s)` would be:

```
String str = "hello  there, what are   you doing      here";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(\s(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\s)", "?"));
=>
hello??there, what are???you doing??????here
```

So the above matches whitespace followed by whitespace , or whitespace preceeded by whitespace and replaces this with "?".

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\s{2,}");
String str = "hello  there, what are   you doing";
System.out.println(pat.matcher(str).replaceAll(m -> "?".repeat(m.group().length())));
```

output:

```
hello??there, what are???you doing
```